# [UWP][MVVMLight][Hamburger Menu]Navigation Service Limitations?

Tags: uwp, navigation, mvvm-light

I'm using MVVMLight (v 5.4.1) in my UWP app and wanted to implement the classic Hamburger menu, where my assorted content pages are displayed in a Frame within the main page. However, in practice, there doesn't seem to be any way in which I can tell the MVVMLight-supplied NavigationService that it should be using the Frame within the main page for navigation. From what I've researched on the net it seems that I have to write my own NavigationService (as defined in this link:  https://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/implementing-viewmodel-based-navigation-in-your-universal-app/ ). Is this really the case? Do I really have to write my own NavigationService or have I missed something obvious?

Surely the Hamburger menu must be one of the most popular app styles, is it really the case that MVVMLight can't completely support it?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I really have to write my own NavigationService or have I missed something obvious?

`MVVMLight` has provided [`NavigationService`](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform%20(UWP)/Views/NavigationService.cs#L28). You have no need to reproduce it.

In order to use the Navigation in MVVM Light you will have to register and Configure INavigationService in ViewModelLocator.cs , for this you will have to register each Page with a PageKey.

```
public const string FirstPageKey = "FirstPage";  
public const string SecondPageKey = "SecondPage";

var nav = new NavigationService();
nav.Configure(FirstPageKey, typeof(FirstPage));
nav.Configure(SecondPageKey, typeof(SecondPage));
```

Comment: Hi @NicoZhu, I read the blog link but that only shows one page navigating to another (and back). I wanted specifically a frame in my Main Page to be the host for all my other content Pages. To accomplish this I thought that the Navigation Service needs to know about that frame in the Main Page (as shown in the link in my question). There doesn't seem to be a way of passing that frame to the Navigation Service.

Comment: I know your means. Actually, the frame does not  stay in the host  `MainPage`. In general, we need to create a **shell**  as a host prior to `MainPage` within hamburg menu architecture . And you could use shell's `NavigationService` to navigate another page that also contain `MainPage`. You could refer [Template 10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10).

Comment: Hi @NicoZhu, many thanks for your reply. From what I gather from what you're saying, my app should have a 'shell' page that hosts both the Main Page and subsequent content pages. If this is the case then that's not what I've read of the Hamburger menu implementation (see my Link). I think it's probably easier for me to create my own Navigation Service as shown in my Link.

Comment: Sure, you could create your own Navigation Service.